# Is it possible to use emacsclient to pre-load emacs, but have each window operate independently?

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs-server

I have been really enjoying having emacs load as a daemon when I login and using `emacsclient -c` to pop open an emacs window *superquick*.

However, I often have multiple emacs windows open at a time. Each one is dedicated to a particular project. Before I used emacsclient each of these emacs windows would be independent of the other, but now, they share the same set of buffers.

How can I continue to use emacsclient, but have the windows act independently?

Comment: When you say "independent", do you mean that you run multiple Emacs applications? It's doable to let `emacsclient` talk to different Emacs applications, depending on where in directory tree you are, but you would have to build the infrastructure for this yourself. Emacs emacs must start an emacs server using different server names, see `server-name`.

Comment: Really, I think that all I care about is that each window has its own buffer list. I like the speed of starting emacs as a daemon, but I want it to behave as if each time I open it it is a new instance of emacs.

Comment: That's a different approach. I haven't seen any package that does this -- in Emacs it's kind of built into the system that all buffers are visible in all frames. Another idea would be to always have one Emacs in deamon mode, waiting for connections. Once you send a file to it, you can start a new Emacs in deamon mode.